# Access the ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

The [ActiveMQ Artemis docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/web-server.html) state that the console is configured in `bootstrap.xml` as follows:

> The embedded Jetty instance is configured in etc/bootstrap.xml via the web element, e.g.:
>
> ```xml
> <web path="web">
>    <binding uri="http://localhost:8161">
>       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
>       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
>       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
>    </binding>
> </web>
> ```
>
> The `web` element has the following attributes:
>
> `path`: The name of the subdirectory in which to find the web application archives (i.e. WAR files). This is a subdirectory of the broker's home or instance directory.

The broker instance does not have the `web` directory. Should the `web` folder with the Web ARchive be copied into the broker instance directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

Notice that the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation says this about the `web` directory (emphasis mine):

> This is a subdirectory of the broker's home **or** instance directory.

By default the necessary archives for the web console are in the broker's *home* directory so there should be no need to create a `web` directory on the *instance* and copy those files there.

When the broker starts you should see logging like this by default:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://localhost:8161/console
```

If you point your browser to the specified URL you'll be able to log in to the web console with the credentials you configured when you created the broker with the `artemis create` command.